# Looking for werewolf horror book where werewolves have to feed on graveyard corpses

Tags: story-identification, books, horror, werewolf

Looking for a book I once found. Published late 70s, early 80s? Horror story where people killed by werewolf return to life as werewolves but find that they are cursed to feed on graveyard corpses.

Comment: any other details? if that is the only unusual thing about this type of werewolf, my editorial remark is, So what?

Comment: Could this be something from H. P. Lovecraft, or a story inspired by his work? Lovecraftian ghouls have canine features.